# Sort rows in database Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've database with a lot of entries and with help of some friends here i manage how to remove the duplicates lines [deleting-duplicate-rows-in-a-mysql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678732/deleting-duplicate-rows-in-a-mysql-database) but now i've to face new problem with is unsorted rows.

here is example of my database now

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (784, 'Albert', 'EGYPT', '202020');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (21, 'John', 'USA', '984731');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (56, 'Albert', 'EGYPT', '343354');
```

as you can see at `id [784,21,56]` so is there any how i can resort it to be

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (1, 'Albert', 'EGYPT', '202020');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (2, 'John', 'USA', '984731');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (3, 'Albert', 'EGYPT', '343354');
```

`id [1,2,3,4,....etc]` resort it , I'm aware that change in ID may cause problems in script itself since it depends on id to garb the entry informations but since it is new then i need to sort it 1,2,3,4,.....etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about puting an [**auto increment**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) on your table?

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then you just need to insert values without specifying ids.

**[EDIT]**

You could also order your rows like this **without changing anything in your table structure**

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank, t.*
from my_table t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
order by rank;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you delete the ID field and create it again (with autoincrement) this will fix your problem.
But I never checked this so first make a backup of your database.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you want to do it, I'm pretty sure removing the id field and adding it again (indexed and with autoincrement) will renumber the rows.

I'm not sure, though, because it's not the kind of thing I've ever done. Are you *sure* you want to do this? What does it matter if they're numbered strangely?

Also, there's no guarantee that MySQL will renumber the rows the way you want - it might well jumble them up a bit.

If you want them ordered by country, or something, you'd have to use some PHP and update the rows one by one, which isn't as hard as it might sound.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)  column:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and then insert:

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('Albert', 'EGYPT', '202020');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('John', 'USA', '984731');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('Albert', 'EGYPT', '343354');
```

Comment: Impossible! for 150K entries to do this got to remove the already exist un-ordered ID !

Answer (score 1):

this question ( [Reorder the database record rows through front-end using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641017/reorder-the-database-record-rows-through-front-end-using-php) ) does exactly what you want, although it uses php to accomplish the task.

grts,

M.